# Django: html not displaying form using block content

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3lOc.png)

```css
//form.html

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<form {% if form_id %} id='{{ form_id }}' {% endif %} class='form' method='POST' action="{% if action_url %}{{ action_url }}{% endif %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{{ btn_title }}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
//list_view.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-12' style='background-color:red;'>
        <h1>{{ request.user }}</h1>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 '>
            {% if not request.GET.q %}
                <div class="">
                    {% include "tweets/form.html" with form=create_form action_url=create_url
                    btn_title='Tweet' form_id='tweet-form' %}
                </div>
                <hr>
            {% endif %}

            <div id="tweet-container">
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

For some reason when I try to use the form.html within the block content of list_view.html it only returns {% include "tweets/form.html" with form=create_form action_url=create_url
                    btn_title='Tweet' form_id='tweet-form' %} 
as you can see in the photo I posted. im trying to make it a text area with a submit button. Does anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include another html file using include tags, don't have to use block content and endblock tags on that particular file. On the file where you want to include the html just use this tag inside the block content.

```
 {% include 'form.html' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with that problem, and found the answer. It's very simple:

```
{% include "tweets/form.html" with form=create_form action_url=create_url btn_title='Tweet' form_id='tweet-form' %}
```

The above line has to be on a *single* line. Don't split it!